# CSS: Image width to resize and fit the browser width dynamically

Tags: html, css

I have made a code to resize and set the width of an image to that of the browser dynamically, so I have set the following code in css

```
max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
```

My challenge is that the image never resizes dynamically to occupy the entire screen width of the browser dynamically.
Here is a Plnker I have made
http://plnkr.co/edit/j6JBCaKBmVQV1PDAh3dZ?p=preview
What could be wrong.

Comment: Plunker link is not working check that you provided the right one.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/j6JBCaKBmVQV1PDAh3dZ?p=preview     This is the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `max-width` to `width`.

As should be obvious from the naming, `max-width` only acts as an upper limit. It does not make anything bigger, it merely downsizes things if they already are bigger than what you specify there.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/b18axhzg/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To squeze it if the parent becomes too small:

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto;
```

To force it taking up the whole with:

```
display: block;
width: 100%; 
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property for img.

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

or max-width:100%;
it will automatic become resizeable.

Answer (score -2):

change max-width: 100%; to width :100%